# Python for data analytics

Tags: data-mining, python

What are some data analytic package & feature in python which helps do data analytic?

Comment: I think most common ones are `numpy`, `scipy`, `scikit-learn` and `pandas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for this answer: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Python-a-language-of-choice-for-data-scientists